# Select multiple fields from subquery

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the next query:

```
SELECT
    a.Date,
    (SELECT SUM(Used), SUM(Max) FROM Switch_Statistic b WHERE Date = (SELECT MAX(Date) FROM Switch_Statistic WHERE Switch_ID = b.Switch_ID AND Date <= a.Date))
FROM Switch_Statistic a
GROUP BY Date;
```

As you see I need to select `SUM(Used), SUM(Max)` from subquery. With `CONCAT` is not good solution!

**Table schema:**

```
ID --- Switch_ID --- Date --- Max --- Used
```

Some data:

```
1   641 2014-10-04  2   16
20  630 2014-10-04  1   7
24  634 2014-10-04  0   8
26  641 2014-10-06  2   16
32  641 2014-10-07  2   16
35  641 2014-10-08  3   16
39  641 2014-10-09  2   16
64  293 2014-10-10  1   22
...
557 38  2014-10-12  3   22
559 293 2014-10-12  1   22
563 294 2014-10-12  6   22
565 641 2014-10-12  2   16
```

What I need:
Example with CONCAT_WS

```
mysql> SELECT
    a.Date,
    (SELECT CONCAT_WS('/', SUM(Used), SUM(Max)) FROM Switch_Statistic b WHERE Date = (SELECT MAX(Date) FROM Switch_Statistic WHERE Switch_ID = b.Switch_ID AND Date <= a.Date)) AS Result
FROM Switch_Statistic a
GROUP BY Date;
+------------+----------+
| Date       | Result   |
+------------+----------+
| 2014-10-04 | 3/31     |
| 2014-10-06 | 3/31     |
| 2014-10-07 | 3/31     |
| 2014-10-08 | 4/31     |
| 2014-10-09 | 3/31     |
| 2014-10-10 | 249/1587 |
| 2014-10-11 | 354/2147 |
| 2014-10-12 | 360/2185 |
+------------+----------+
8 rows in set (0.26 sec)
```

Query logic:
1) Select all date's from table
2) SUM - Used and Max for current date, if Switch_ID don't have record for this date, then select the last which exists in table

Link to sqlfiddle - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c3d479

Comment: Can you please share your tables structure, some sample data, and what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: so what is ur question ??

Comment: Edit your question and add your desired results.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this with just aggregation and no subqueries or joins:

```
  SELECT date, sum(used) as used, sum(max) as max
  FROM switch_statistic ss
  where ss.date = (select max(date) from Switch_Statistics ss2 where ss2.Switch_id = ss.SwitchId
  GROUP BY ss.date;
```

EDIT:

You seem to want a cumulative sum.  In MySQL, this is often best done using variables:

```
SELECT date, used, max, (@u := @u + used) as cumeused, @m := @m + max) as cumemax
fROM (SELECT date, sum(used) as used, sum(max) as max
      FROM switch_statistic ss
      GROUP BY ss.date
     ) ss CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT @u := 0, @m := 0) vars
ORDER BY date;
```

Comment: cumeused, cumeused are shown me as null and result are also incorrect. Your query have a little bit wrong logic, look at my query.